# Android MediaRecorder Fragment how to keep the same instance

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera2

I have a `MediaRecorder` class, that extends `Fragment`. Inside that `class` I have created methods to `set up the MediaRecorder` and also methods to `start` and `stop` recording.

I have tried creating `onTouch` withing the `Fragment` and using `start/stop` inside the fragment on `button` presses and it worked. But when I removed `onTouch` and tried to use the `start/stop` methods from another class I got `NullPointerException`. To be more precise, it gave no `error` when pressing `start` but gave an `error` when I pressed `stop`!

After debugging `startRecordingVideo` all 3 -> (`mCameraDevice, mTextureView, mPreviewSize`) are `null` so it does not even start recording and during `stopRecordingVideo` the `mMediaRecorder` is also null.

Here is the part where I try to use the `MediaRecorderFragment` inside another class:

```
private Camera2VideoFragment camera2VideoFragment;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.song_player);
    //Camera2Video
    camera2VideoFragment = new Camera2VideoFragment();

    //Start Camera Preview
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, Camera2VideoFragment.newInstance())
            .commit();



    playRecordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) {
             final int action = motionevent.getAction();
             if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                //Start recording video
                startRecordingVideo();

           } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                //Stop Recording Video
                stopRecordingVideo();

           }
            return false;
        }
    }); 
}   

private void startRecordingVideo(){
    camera2VideoFragment.startVideoRecording();
}

private void stopRecordingVideo(){
    camera2VideoFragment.stopVideoRecording();
}
```

The `MediaRecorderFragment` can be [found here.](https://pastebin.com/dLjM6YBE) (This class is too long to post here).

My question is, why do I get the `NullPointerException` and how can I make that `fragment` work from another `class`.

Comment: what is null? Maybe `startPreview ()` in `stopVideoRecording()` is the problem?

Comment: I debugged it and during `startRecordingVideo` all 3 -> (`mCameraDevice, mTextureView, mPreviewSize`) are `null` so it does not even start recording and during `stopRecordingVideo` the `mMediaRecorder` is also null.

Comment: You have 2 onTouch Listeners, both calling startVideoRecording. One in your main Activity, the other in your `Camera2VideoFragment`. It is probably complaining about null because you open it twice per touch.